# Functions with Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have some function which I need to call in my view(comment.bade.php) and return $id, this is function:

```
function tree($id) {
            $childs = DB::table('replays')->where('order', $id)->first();
            return view('comment',  compact('childs'));
  }
```

I don't know right way to do it in Laravel 5, could someone help me where to put function and how to call it into my comment.blade.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you add custom functions, or "helpers" to Laravel 5.

First we need to store our helpers somewhere. In my example, I'm creating a file named `helpers.php` under the `app` directory in a clean install of Laravel 5. Within that file I have the following code:

```
<?php

if ( ! function_exists('tree'))
{
    function tree($id)
    {
        // `app` is a built-in L5 helper function
        // it returns our applications container instance
        return app('db')->table('replays')->where('order', '=', $id)->first();
    }
}
```

Next your app will need to load these functions. I'm going to use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to load them. Within the root folder of the Laravel 5 install you'll see a file called `composer.json` open that and you'll see an `autoload` section, modify that to look something like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

Finally you'll need to refresh the composer autoload, so from your [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) you will need to type: `composer dumpautoload`.

You should now be able to call the function from anywhere within your Laravel application.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to make any bd code on an specific service just for retrieve db values from that table and initialize any variable that you will use on the view on the controller method.

Comment: class CommentController extends Controller {

    public function comment($id)
    {
        $childs = DB::table('replays')->where('order', $id)->first();
         return view('comment',  compact('childs'));
    }

}
You can do it in the controller like that. But i recommend you that you better move this code to a service of your own

Comment: That code is already in controller but don't know how to call that function from my blade: comment.bade.php so I can return $id value....

Comment: You should not call any function from the view. Set up any variables in your controller and use then in the view. The view should not have any logic further than a if or a loop.

Comment: In my view is foreach loop and I need when in that loop get certain $id to call my function something like this CommentController::comment($id);, any idea how to do that?

Comment: It is important that you keep the logic separate from the view. If you need data associated to each row from another table you should use a join clause in sql. Or make a helper of your own